# Renaming Multiple Files on macOS Terminal

Tags: bash, macos, shell, file-rename

Is it possible to rename multiple files that share a similar name but are different types of files all at once?

Example:

> apple.png
>
> apple.pdf
>
> apple.jpg

Can I substitute the apple for something else, for example "pear"? If this is possible, what would the command be? Many thanks for your time!

Comment: There is no standard tool or anything built in to `bash` that will do this. There are various implementations of `rename` commands available that can, however.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this in bash natively by looping over the files beginning `apple` and renaming each one in turn using bash [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

```
$ for f in apple*; do mv "$f" "${f/apple/pear}"; done
```

The `for f in apple*` finds all files matching the wildcard. Each filename is then assigned to the variable `f`
For each assignment to `f` bash calls the command `mv` to move (rename) the file from it's existing name to one where `apple` is replaced by `pear`

You could also install `rename` using a package manager like Homebrew and call

```
rename -e 's/apple/pear/' apple*
```

Comment: `for..in` works perfectly for `zsh`, but not for `bash` :)

Comment: This worked perfectly when I removed the double quotes in the command.